# Best way to pick numerous slices from a Dask array

Tags: dask, dask-distributed

I'm generating a large (65k x 65k x 3) 3D signal distributed among several nodes using Dask arrays. 
In the next step, I need to extract a few thousands tiles from this array using slices stored in a Dask bag. My code looks like this:

```py
import dask.array as da
import dask.bag as db
from dask.distributed import Client

def pick_tile(window, signal):
    return np.array(surface[window])

def computation_on_tile(signal_tile):
   # do some rather short computation on a (n x n x 3) signal tile.

dask_client = Client(....)

signal_array = generate_signal(...)  # returns a dask array
signal_slices = db.from_sequence(generate_slices(...))  # fixed size slices

signal_tiles = signal_slices.map(pick_tile, signal=signal_array)

result = dask_client.compute(signal_tile.map(computation_on_tile), sync=True)
```

My issue is that the computation takes a lot of time. I tried to scatter my signal array using:

```py
signal_array = dask_client.scatter(generate_signal(...))
```

But it doesn't help performance (~12 min. to compute). In comparison, the computation of the full signal and the stdev of the first layer takes approximately 2 minutes.

Is there an efficient way to pick a lot of slices from a distributed Dask array ?

Answer (score 0):

If you have only a few thousand slices then I recommend using a normal Python list rather than Dask Bag.  It will likely be much faster and much simpler.

Then you can slice your array many times:

```
tiles = [dask_array[slc] for slc in slices]
```

And compute these if you want

```
tiles = dask.compute(*tiles)
```

Comment: Thank for your answer @MRocklin, however, I'd like to keep them in a Bag because in a step I need to perform a cartesian product between these slices and a rather huge Bag and then perform a more complex computation. Would you mind if I submit an issue on github Dask repo to provide more details ?